# Regular Expression To Fail On Character In One Place But Match If Character Used Later On

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression (Javascript) that can take whitespace followed by an optional sign [-+] followed by number characters [0-9.,] followed by more optional whitespace. What I want to do is make sure the next character is not +,-,*,/ or ^. The next character can be any other text and, once that other text is entered, can then include any math symbols. Here's what I have so far:

```
^\s*[-+]?[0-9,.]+\s*[^-+*/^].*$
```

This allows both "23 +" and "23 df+" to match, though, and I only want the latter example to match. If I leave off the `.*` near the end then "23 +" and "23 df+" both fail. I thought the bracket expression `[^-+*/^]` for the math characters would match the next character and then `.*` would match characters after that, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Can anyone help explain both how to fix it and where I went wrong? I'm new to regex and would like to learn from my mistake.

Update with additional examples.

```
"23" should match

"-23" should match

"23.5" should match

"2,345.5" should match

"23+" should not match (same for -,asterisk,/,^)

"23 +" should not match (same for -,asterisk,/,^)

"23 text" should match

"23 text+" should match (same for -,asterisk,/,^ in place of +)

"23 text +" should match (same for -,asterisk,/,^ in place of +)
```

Comment: Maybe it's in your text, but can you give examples to matches that are valid and invalid.

Comment: Is the `+` sign required?

Comment: Note that when you use the `*` quantifier it may match 0 times and that's what happens here.

Comment: @progenhard, I added some additional examples.

Comment: @Broxzier no the + is not required. I added some more examples.

Comment: @eliajf thanks for the clarification. I posted a regex that works for your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (with slightly modification as per [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727519/regular-expression-to-fail-on-character-in-one-place-but-match-if-character-used/18727649?noredirect=1#comment27601286_18727649)):

```
^\s*[-+]?[0-9,.]+\s*(\s*[^-+*/^\s0-9]+\s*[-+]*)*$
```

Works 100% for your test cases (as of the [third revision of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18727519/3)).

---

FYI, I've included *0-9* in here: `[^-+*/^\s0-9]+`, so the greedyness doesn't affect the second 'part' of your text.

Comment: That's very close based on an initial test. The "23+" case is legit, though, which means maybe I'm focusing on the wrong spot. I want to basically ignore whitespace. The `\s*` seems to impact that. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for the help. I, of course, found another test case ("34 ") but was able to solve it with a slight modification. `^\s*[-+]?[0-9,.]+\s*(\s*[^-+*/^\s0-9]+\s*[-+]*)*$`

Comment: @eliajf You're welcome. I incorporated your regex into my answer, now.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is greedy. Therefore it tries to match ALWAYS, whenever it can.

So in the case of the String "23 +", your regex would do the following:

- `[0-9,.]+` matches the 23
- `\s*` matches **NOTHING** (due to the `*`)
- `[^-+*/^]` will match your whitespace.
- `.*` will match the "+".

(Update: See here: http://regex101.com/r/gY5pS1)

Using your pattern, you need to minimize the last group by exluding whitespaces AND numbers.

`^\s*[-+]?[0-9,.]+\s*[^-\s0-9+*/^].*$`

Just adding whitespaces will cause your regex to take a wrong match again, starting to capture the "3" with that group:

- `[0-9,.]+` would match the 2
- `\s*` would match **NOTHING**
- `[^-\s+*/^]` would match 3
- `.*` would match the rest.

(Update: See here: http://regex101.com/r/yA3tA6)

Obviously wrong, so exclude 0-9 from the last group also. I Hope this covers both your questions.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate: a greedy repeater (like `*`) will match if it can. It won't "cancel" the match later on unless it's backtracking. You can use a non-greedy repeater (like `*?`) for that.

Comment: @Eric: If Regex has the choice between *no match* and *match* (for the complete pattern) it will take the match. No matter how many `*` Operators need to match zero.

Comment: @Eric: http://regex101.com/r/gY5pS1 See here, it matches exactly the way I predicted it.

Comment: Yes, in most cases, but that's called backtracking and has little to do with greediness. It's a property of the runtime, some engines will some won't.

Comment: @Eric this has *absolutely* nothing to do with backtracking. It's simple the fact, that the regex fails at some point, and continues from the *same* position within the source-string, but with the next pattern. Since the `*` will also match *nothing* it's just logical to continue with attempts, where star *is* matching nothing.

Comment: @Eric Thx, I know what backtracking is. You're right, that the match-algorithm might work that way. And I have to admit, that I thought you were talking about back*references*.

Comment: No worries, and indeed, this only makes a difference for engines that don't backtrack. But learning about greediness is useful to optimise regexen, which is why i'm so anal =)

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead, maybe something like `/[-+]?[0-9,.]+\s*(?![+\-*/\^\s0-9,.])/`.

Note that what you want to match is also in that lookahead, because otherwise it'd just break off in the middle of the string, for example "23+" would match the "2"  because "3" not one of those disallowed characters.

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches only the ones in your example that you want it to match:

```
[-+]?[0-9,.]+(\s+[a-z]+\s*[-+*\/^]?)?
```

Here's an illustration to show you how it works:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
'23' // true
'-23' // true
'23.5' // true
'2,345.5' // true
'23+' // false
'23 +' // false
'23 text' // true
'23 text+' // true
'23 text +' // true
```

Don't forget to add the `/i` flag to turn off case sensitivity.

Comment: May I ask how did you draw/generate that image?

Answer (score 0):

Using negative lookahead you can use this regex:

```
/^\s*[-+]?[\d,.]+\b(?!\s*[-+*\/^]).*$/
```